# WM_KEYDOWN confusion

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to get my application to do something when CTRL+S is pressed. I'm just not sure how the W and L params work for WM_KEYDOWN. MSDN has something about bit fields which i'm not sure about. How can I detect CTRL and S?
Thanks

What do I do if another control aside from hWnd has focus?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(VS.85).aspx) is the big list of virtual key codes.

CTRL-S is going to be sent through as 2 `WM_KEYDOWN` messages - a message when the ctrl key is pressed (`VK_LCONTROL` or `VK_RCONTROL`) followed by a `0x53` for the "S" key.

Rather than processing both messages, wait for the key down message for the 'S' press then call [GetKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646301(VS.85).aspx) using the magic value VK_CONTROL (otheriwse you'd need to test individually for the left AND right control keys) to see if the S was pressed with CTRL held down.

--

Obviously, keyboard messages are sent directly to the window that has focus. To get accelerator combinations to work at the application scope you need to check the messages before dispatching them to the focus window - i.e. in your message pump. See the documentation for [TranslateAccelerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646373(VS.85).aspx).

If you want to handle system wide keypresses, the other answer points to the  hot key api.

Comment: What do I do is another control aside from hWnd has focus?

Comment: To handle ctrl-X combinations app wide you would use the accelerator api. Systemwide - the hotkey api.

Comment: But how do you ensure it's exactly `Ctrl-S` — instead of `Ctrl-Alt-S` or something else?

Comment: @SnzFor16Min: There is a “free” way to check in-particular-for-`Alt`: check `contextCode = (lParam >> 29) & 0x1`.  But to handle “all meaningful modifiers” you better get the whole `GetKeyboardState` and go through all the relevant bytes.  (However one should limit themselves: many pseudo-keys [“are supposed to stay pressed”](https://metacpan.org/dist/UI-KeyboardLayout/view/lib/UI/KeyboardLayout.pm#Far-Eastern-keyboards-on-Windows).  So only the relevant codes should be checked.)

Answer (score -2):

When the WPARAM is equal to the CTRL VKcode, then set a bool in the state of your object. Then, when S comes up, if Ctrlbool, you've got CTRL-S.

Comment: What if he leaves Ctrl key before pressing S? Then you need to handle keyup messages to track it. Chris' reply is the appropriate approach.